# Does this means SSLv3 is enabled?

Tags: ssl

With New,  , Cipher is  does it means that SSLV3 is enabled or disabled?

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : SSLv3
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    Start Time: 1403907236
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CONNECTED(00000003)
> write:errno=104
> ....
> SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 0 bytes
> ...
>     Cipher    : 0000
> ```

This means that no SSL handshake was done (no bytes transferred for SSL handshake). The attempt to initiate the handshake caused errno=104 which is at least on Linux "Connection reset by peer". This is caused by the server closing the connection to the client immediately after the TCP connection setup.

Comment: So does this mean that it is SSLV3 is disabled?

Comment: @Alvin567: The connection failed before any information could be exchanged. Thus no statement can be done which protocols the server would have been supported if you managed to continue with the connection.

Comment: Hi thanks, New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE) if it is for this does it tell anything about the server?

Comment: @Alvin567: again and again: no data got transferred so no information about the server are known and thus these information don't tell you anything about the server.

Comment: Hi Steffen, Is there an alternative way of getting information from the server to check if SSL v3 is enabled. I used Scanning tools like Nessus it says there is Poodle, but OpenSSL as you can see it does not get anything

Comment: @Alvin567:  Since the server simply closes the connection after the TCP connect was successful you have to find out why it does it and how to prevent it. This has nothing to do with SSL, OpenSSL or whatever!! Maybe the server simply blocks your IP address in which case you have to try from somewhere elese.

Comment: Hi Steffen, is there a way to check if the SSLv3 is really closed?

Comment: @Alvin567:  since you cannot communicate with the server from your current position you cannot determine the supported SSL versions of the server from there. Thus you must try from somewhere else.